# Highcharts - three series using left Y axis and the fourth using the right Y axis

Tags: jquery, highcharts, series

I have a graph where I am displaying three volume series (oil, gas, and water) using the left Y axis.  I need to display another series for the number of wells on this graph using a different scale along the right axis.  the code is shown below:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
    new Highcharts.Chart({
      chart: {
        renderTo: 'volume_chart',
        type: 'line'
      },
      title: {
        text: "#{title_text}"
      },
      xAxis: {
        title: { text: 'Time Period' },
        tickInterval: #{tick_interval},
        categories: #{x_array},
        showLastLabel: true,
        labels: {
          rotation: -45,
          align: 'right',
          style: {
              font: 'normal 13px Verdana, sans-serif'
          }
        }        
      },
      yAxis: {
        title: { text: 'Volume' },
        type: 'logarithmic'
      },
      tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br />',
        pointFormat: 'Period = {point.x}, Volume = {point.y}'
      },
      legend: {
          layout: 'vertical',
          align: 'right',
          verticalAlign: 'top',
          x: -20,
          y: 100,
          borderWidth: 0
      },
      plotOptions: {
          series: {
              marker: {
                  enabled: false,
                  states: {
                      hover: {
                          enabled: true
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      },
      series: [{
        name: 'Oil, bbl',
        color: 'green',
        data: #{oil_vol_array},
        pointStart: 1
      },{
        name: "Gas, Mcf",
        color: 'red',
        data: #{gas_vol_array},
        pointStart: 1
      },{
        name: 'Water, bbl',
        color: 'blue',
        data: #{water_vol_array},
        pointStart: 1
      }]
    });
  });
```

See the three series for Oil, Gas, and Water volumes respectively.  I need to put in another series for number of wells which uses the Y - axis on the right for displaying number of wells.  This also needs to be a logarithmic type.

I would also like to suppress the last tickValue on the x-axis (please see the attached image:

[image: The chart display]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the number of wells on the right Y-Axis, you will need to set up a second Y-Axis. You'll need to change the yAxis into an array as below:

```
yAxis: [{
    title: { text: 'Volume' },
    type: 'logarithmic'
},{
    title: { text: 'Count' },
    type: 'logarithmic'
}]
```

Then, you need to specify the axis you are using for each series...otherwise it will default to the first series. 0 would be the Volume axis and 1 is the Count axis

```
series: [{
    name: 'Oil, bbl',
    color: 'green',
    data: #{oil_vol_array},
    pointStart: 1
},{
    name: "Gas, Mcf",
    color: 'red',
    data: #{gas_vol_array},
    pointStart: 1
},{
    name: 'Water, bbl',
    color: 'blue',
    data: #{water_vol_array},
    pointStart: 1
},{
    name: 'Wells',
    color: 'yellow',
    data: #{wells_vol_array},
    pointStart: 1,
    yAxis: 1
}]
```

The [Highcharts Demo for multiple axes](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-multi-axes) has more options/info that may be helpful.

You can suppress the final category from being displayed easily enough, not sure how you would suppress the actual tick though. Probably the easiest way is to define a list of categories you don't want to display the tickValue for, then add a formatter to the xAxis labels option:

```
var lastCategory = 'Jan 2040';

labels: {
    rotation: -45,
    align: 'right',
    style: {
        font: 'normal 13px Verdana, sans-serif'
    },
    formatter: function() 
    {
        return (this.value != lastCategory) ? this.value : '';
    }
}
```

**Edit: Add tooltip info**

You can do a couple of things here, you can simply change the tooltip option to (as per this [Highcharts JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/tooltip/shared-true-mixed-types/)):

```
tooltip: {
    shared: true
},
```

Or you can go a bit fancier and specify a formatter as shown in [this other Highcharts JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/tooltip/formatter-shared/).

I highly recommend the [Highcharts Reference](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/) it's pretty well laid out with a number of good demos

Comment: Thanks you kind sir, this is precisely what I needed.  The yAxis: 1 bit is what I was missing.  By the way, I could suppress the last category value by simply setting the showLastLabel: false -- under xAxis.  The tooltip is the last bit.  Would you know how can I customize it for the newly added "Wells" axis?  It is showing "Volume" instead of "Wells" even though the right values are displayed?  I really appreciate your help.

Comment: lol, I missed that showLastLabel bit...nice! I've added the tooltip piece to my answer